# Aligning headers in a sidebar (set maximum content-box width)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying out a challenge for CSS and HTML, but hit a snag.

I have a sidebar set up, with some content layered out vertically inside a flexbox. 
For some reason, the headers don't want to align themselves. Some of them "float" away from the others if you will, and it looks all misaligned (the right side seems to hit bang on center, but the left-side sometimes doesn't reach the edge). The only thing that is different to my knowledge is that the content boxes that aren't aligned are smaller in size. 
Post 3 = 627.500 x 160, but Post 4 = 613.625 x 160.

This only happens when the browser is maximised. With smaller viewfinders, the content box sizes become standardised, and everything looks aligned/the headers are pushed up against the sidebar.

Is it possible to set the maximum width of a content box? If not, how do I shift them to the edge of the sidebar like the others? Have I failed to consider something else?

CSS

```
.main{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 29%;
    grid-gap: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #d6710b;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

h1, h2{
    font-family: "Zhi Mang Xing", cursive;
    font-size: 10em;
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar h2{
    padding: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 10px dotted black;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div>
            <h2>Post 1</h2>
            ...
        </div>  
        <div>
            <h2>Post 2</h2>
            ...
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Post 3</h2>
            ...
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Post 4</h2>
            ...
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Post 5</h2>
            ...
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Post 6</h2>
            ...
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

[image: A sidebar, with the headers "post 4" and "post 6" not in line]

https://jsfiddle.net/3q4eskrd/
(don't know why they are sticking out of the sidebar on jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Found the cultprit that's giving me headaches.

```
.sidebar{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:center;
}
```

My flex-direction is a column (forcing the x and y axis to switch, in a manner of speaking). 
So whereas normally align-items arranges items on the x axis, I'm seeing everything being centered on the y axis because of my flex-direction. 
(Subsequently justify-content, which should work on arranging things via their relation to the y-axis, is shifting everything in relation to the x-axis. )

Take out align-items, and I get everything neatly lined-up with no content-box size differences and can make changes from here on out.